# Is it possible to Change Container htmlClass by override Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, containers

I have a container defined in a layout file, but in some case with help of other xml I would like to change its `htmlClass` value, is it possible by override or something ? or need to create new container for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the htmlClass in theme level

For example get the layout into your theme and modify it.

I grab the code from `module-theme`, kept in Luma theme and  added my `htmlclass(mycustomclass).`

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
        <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header **mycustomclass**">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                    <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna, Its worked, but I cannot use `<container name="main.content" ` not sure whats the issue, the contents are empty while use "main.content" named container

Comment: @ Riyas Muhammed Feel free to ask new question with code you have tried.